# Is it possible to change the default request behaviour from react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a `Geomap` with a react-leaflet map doing the map tiles requests to my backend. And for each tile react-leaflet makes a new request only changing `X`, `Y`, and `Zoom` on the URL. 
Is it possible to change the default behaviour like grouping all map tiles requests into one?

```
Example Json Payload:
{
  "tiles": [
    [200,120,2],
    [201,121,2],
    [202,122,2],
    [203,123,2],
  ]
}
```

Where first element is `X`, second is `Y` and the third is the `Zoom level`.

Comment: Yeah, you can use some Leaflet plugins to make untiled WMS requests... but *why*? All current web server architecture (including HTTP2) is kinda optimized for this way of making lots of individual requests one after another.

Comment: Hey @IvanSanchez, thank you for your comment. I'm have a cache between my app and my map provider, because I'm using a free service and it might block me for overuse as it happened before sometimes. So, my app is kind of DDosing myself. That's why I want to group the requests.

Comment: Grouping the map requests together will just increase the CPU load on your proxy server. The set of circumstances where grouping tiles together would help (e.g. 4 256px tiles into a 512px metatile) are really edge cases. This is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you should be looking at the bottleneck (CPU, network, RAM) on your proxy server instead.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. Thank you again @IvanSanchez